# Challenge installing psd-tools on fresh Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, pip

I've been using PSD-TOOLS to great effect on a 13" notebook for half a year now (Python 2.7.3).  Just tried to do a fresh install on a Mac running 10.8.4.

I ran through the python setup at http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/ (Python version

Installed Pil using:

```
sudo pip install pil
```

All my Pil scripts work fine.

```
pip list
```

shows PIL (1.1.7) installed fine.

Then tried to install psd-tools using:

```
sudo pip install psd-tools
```

Appears to install fine but when I run my PSD scripts, get the following:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psd_tools/user_api/psd_image.py", line 91, in as_PIL
return self._psd._layer_as_PIL(self._index)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psd_tools/user_api/psd_image.py", line 243, in _layer_as_PIL
return pil_support.extract_layer_image(self.decoded_data, index)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psd_tools/user_api/pil_support.py", line 32, in extract_layer_image
decoded_data.header.depth, get_icc_profile(decoded_data))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psd_tools/user_api/pil_support.py", line 68, in _channels_data_to_PIL
raise Exception("This module requires PIL (or Pillow) installed.")
Exception: This module requires PIL (or Pillow) installed.
```

Anybody run into this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue on `OSX 10.9` with `Python 2.7.5`. (In a virtualenv)

I ended up going over https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1 and installing some optional prerequisites for Pillow.

```
#I already had libjpeg but this is the line in their doc.
brew install libtiff libjpeg webp littlecms
#Then re-installed Pillow
pip install --force-reinstall --upgrade pillow
```

The result was the following features enabled

```
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- TIFF G3/G4 (experimental) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
--- LITTLECMS support available
--- WEBP support available
--- WEBPMUX support available
```

And my small python test ran

```
from PIL import Image
from psd_tools import PSDImage
psd = PSDImage.load('test_data/1.psd')
merged_image = psd.as_PIL()
```

Not sure which of those requirements was responsible so if you are not interested in installing extra libraries you may have to do 1 at a time or dig into the source.